# Which is best for an android app: Using bitmap or drawing the circle?

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

In my android app I need to have 36 circles on a surfaceview. This can be done either using bitmap of circles or actually drawing circles on canvas. What are the pros and cons of both methods ?

**edit**
The app(game) will have simple circles. Each circle will have only 1 colour but there are total 6 types of colours. Look [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nerdyoctopus.gamedots) to get better idea. For such simple circles what method is recommended ?

**edit 1**
Some interesting concepts I found [here](http://www.xenomachina.com/2011/05/androids-2d-canvas-rendering-pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

The Bitmap class in Android is pretty heavy weight (from the Beginning Android Games book by Zechner and Green). If you had to use a Bitmap from resources, you will need extra space to hold these assets, time to read them in and to reproduce them. With canvas, you do not need any extra space as those circles would be drawn in real time. Also depending upon the assets you might end up having to decode the source into the RGB88, ARGB444, ARGB8888 or RGB565 configurations - extra overhead.

I don't know everything about your case but if you had 36 different circles and 36 different bitmaps for those circles, it is pretty easy to see that this would not be efficient. If they are dimple circles then go for canvas. If they were feature rich (differently colored in different places, had images rendered on the circumference etc.), then Bitmap might make it easier to reproduce them (at the cost of a little extra space though).

Comment: Canvas - definitely. The code will be smaller and more efficient. no bitmap configurations necessary and no additional space for resources.

Comment: 6 bitmaps of simple circles will really not consume much space

Comment: You could but given a choice of consuming very little space and no space, it is still better to go with no space. Besides, there is also a time associated with reading in the asset as an input stream. And don't forget, you might also end up having to scale it to different device sizes.

Comment: btimaps can be decoded using `BitmapFactory.decode...` at the start of the game itself and then it can be reused as many times as i want. r u saying redrawing on canvas is better than reusing the bitmaps ?

Comment: reusing bitmaps has an associated drawing time with rendering. Bitmap by nature is a heavy weight framework. But at the end of the day, it's really up to you to use your discretion as to how you wish to proceed. I am not aware of all the other features that you will be implementing. I have simply mentioned an average case scenario that I came across when working on game development.

Comment: Well what you are unaware is, according to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#draw-with-canvas ,  _...Via the Canvas, your drawing is actually performed upon an underlying **Bitmap**..._

Comment: @TactMayers does that mean drawing a circle using `canvas.drawCircle()` is actually creating a bitmap and posting it on canvas ?

Comment: Yes, that's right as the doc says. That means whether you decode an image or use a `Canvas`, you'll still need a `Bitmap` of the same size in terms of memory.

Comment: @TactMayers If that is the case then isn't it better to use bitmap than to draw on canvas since i need animation hence the rendering has to be fast ?

Comment: I'm not sure about speed and performance aspect of decoding a bitmap VS directly drawing on Canvas. I'd suggest you write some real code on both methods to gauge the performance of them.

Answer (score 0):

You  can  take  acont  which  one  is  you best  skills,  drawing  or  programing. If  you  draw  the  bitmaps have that use more  ram but it  render fast, take  care  decode and cache all  bitmap  before.  if  you  draw by using  the circles function it could be spend  more time rendering and  time  programing.

Comment: why drawing circle using `canvas.drawCircle` will take more time than drawing bitmap ? bitmap has more data to be displayed since it is a rectangle surrounding the circle.

Comment: It  needs  compute  the bondary of cicle,  for  other  hand  I  am no sure that trasnparent pixel take a lot of  work